# Removing entries from the MobileMe synchronization list

Tags: snow-leopard, mobileme, preferences

Some applications can synchronize data using MobileMe synchronization; the problem I have with those applications is that they are still listen in the MobileMe preference panel, under the "Synchronize" tab, even when they have been uninstalled. I use a tool to remove any files associated with an application, when I don't need it anymore.

Is there a way to refresh the list of settings to synchronize, and avoid that removed applications are visible in that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program injected data into `~/Library/Application Support/SyncServices/Local/TFSM` by calling code to [add their sync schema](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/SyncServicesFramework/Classes/ISyncManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ISyncManager/registerSchemaWithBundlePath%3a) to Mobile Me's local sync database. You want that program to call [unregisterSchemaWithName](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/SyncServicesFramework/Classes/ISyncManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ISyncManager/unregisterSchemaWithName%3a) before you delete it so that data is deleted out of MobileMe.

The Local SyncServices folder governs iOS device sync as well as MobileMe sync - so use care to keep those devices away from your mac if you with to proceed in a manual clean up.

It's a really bad idea to simply delete files out of that folder if you are not prepared to have sync break in very ugly ways (I have seen people end up with 10 copies of each contact, calendar item and bookmark by moving / disturbing things in SyncServices) If you have a great backup and don't mind erasing everything from MobileMe and re-syncing from a computer - have at hacking the folder. There's no better way to know how things work by breaking them. Apple has an eloquent warning that starts... ["As if it were a swarm of bees, you should stay away from the SyncServices folder."](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1865)

You can see what a sync schema looks like by reading the database of files on your mac in the terminal `locate syncschema`. These files and folders define how data gets injected into the sync database with the [registerSchemaWithBundlePath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/SyncServicesFramework/Classes/ISyncManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ISyncManager/registerSchemaWithBundlePath%3a) call and may have clues on cleanup scripts or steps.

Your best bet is to contact the vendor and ask them what steps to take to undo their changes. Apple has been changing the internals of how mobile me works lately, so there are no for certain steps that work across all versions of 10.6.x and your specific data in MobileMe. Since MobileMe is a paid service, you might also get general guidance from Apple Support in cleaning up the preference pane even though it's a third party data addition. They did add hooks and intend to let other apps to the sync party so they might reasonably help you clean up after the fun is over.

Comment: I thought there was a way to force Mac OS X to refresh the list of the applications that integrate with Mobile Me synchronization, or at least that is what I remember I did 3-4 years ago, when I had the same "problem." I don't remember which command line I used, nor if I used a command line at all.

Comment: It was easier when iSync was in charge of everything. It could still be possible but it's well hidden from me :-)

Answer (score 0):

The tool I used 3-4 years ago was Syncrospector. It allows to unregister clients, and schemas; what is shown in the MobileMe preference panel are the registered clients.

[image: screenshot]